# Why can't I find my SQLite database in filesystem?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm pretty new to SQLite database implementations in Android, so I might have overlooked something. I have created a SQLite database with a class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` :

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "/mnt/sdcard/db/db.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";

    public static final String TABLE_EXTRA_DATA = "extra_data";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_LINKED_ORDER_NUMBER = "linked_order_number";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_ARRIVAL_TIME = "arrival_time";
    public static final String KEY_ARRIVAL_IMPORTANT = "arrival_important";
    public static final String KEY_CLIENT_NAME = "client_name";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_EXTRA_DATA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_EXTRA_DATA + " (" +
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            KEY_LINKED_ORDER_NUMBER + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            KEY_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            KEY_ARRIVAL_TIME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            KEY_ARRIVAL_IMPORTANT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            KEY_CLIENT_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + " )";

    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EXTRA_DATA;

    private final Activity _context;

    public DB(Activity context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EXTRA_DATA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DELETE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

And I have a database helper class to use operations on the database :

```
public class DbHelper {
    private DB _dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase _db;

    public DbHelper(Activity context)
    {
        _dbHelper = new DB(context);
        _db = _dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void CloseDb() {
        if (_db != null)
        {
            if (_db.isOpen())
                _db.close();
        }
    }

    public void SaveExtraData() {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(_dbHelper.KEY_ID,"test");
        cv.put(_dbHelper.KEY_DATE,"test");
        cv.put(_dbHelper.KEY_ARRIVAL_TIME,"test");
        cv.put(_dbHelper.KEY_ARRIVAL_IMPORTANT,"test");
        cv.put(_dbHelper.KEY_CLIENT_NAME,"test");

        _db.insert(_dbHelper.TABLE_EXTRA_DATA, null, cv);
    }
}
```

I get no errors when initiating the database and databaseHelper in an activity and adding some data on the database :

```
if(_db == null) {
    _db = new DbHelper(this);
}
try {
    _db.SaveExtraData();
    _db.CloseDb();
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

But I can't find the database anywhere on the filesystem on my device. I'm testing it on a Motorola TC55 with android version 4.4.3

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's located in the `/data/data/<packageNameOfYourApp>/databases/` folder by default, although you cannot access this folder unless your device is rooted.

The `openDatabase()` method of `SQLiteDatabase` lets you provide a path for your database.

For example:

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/pathToYourDb/yourDBFile.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Or, using `SQLiteOpenHelper` you could do something like this:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "/pathToYourDb/yourDBFile.db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways to access your database file. You can use the following adb command to copy the database to your local machine:

`adb exec-out run-as APP_PACKAGE cat databases/DB_NAME.db > filename`

Another approach is to implement backup and restore functionality. When you run a backup, copy your database to a public location. On restore, copy it back to your app location. Here is a sample restore function:

```
public void restoreDatabase() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String backupDBPath = "//data//YOUR_PACKAGE//databases//DB_NAME.db";
            String currentDBPath = "sdcard/BACKUP_NAME.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Use the reverse of the code above to backup.